# multiple drawers one on click with custom list and other on slide in react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, frontend, navigation-drawer

I have a main navigation drawer which directs to all the screens,and in one of the  screen i want a functionality when we click on a button,a new drawer should open from the left with custom list which comes from the api ,if i click on any of the item in the list,it should redirect to the  same screen with different props.how to solve this?should i have to use multiple navigation drawer or is there any other approach?

should i have to use multiple navigation drawer or is there any other approach?

Comment: please see [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.